# How to use command line to insert plantuml code into draw.io and output diagram as headless option?

Tags: command-line, diagrams

I know it's possible to insert plantuml into draw.io and output a diagram using the GUI. See https://www.drawio.com/blog/plantuml for example.

I know it's possible to use command line to get draw.io desktop to generate different formats like pdf, png, svg for diagrams. see https://tomd.xyz/how-i-use-drawio/ for example.

What I want to do is combine both:

- Using command line only (or any other headless methods like calling API),
- when the input is plantuml code ONLY
- generate the diagram in draw.io XML format, or .svg

Is this possible? If not, is there a way to stitch them together?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Perl script available here:

[PlantUML to Draw.io Perl Script on Github](https://github.com/rglaue/plantuml_to_drawio)

> Convert a file with PlantUML code into a Diagrams.net (a.k.a Draw.io)
> XML file from the command line

To use it:

```
./plantuml_to_drawio_xml.pl foo.plantuml > foo.drawio.xml
```

The README describes what the script is doing:

1. Convert PlantUML plain text data to SVG data using java and the PlantUML jar Encode the PlantUML SVG data using Base64
2. Encode the PlantUML text data for XML/HTML/URL format
3. Obtain the SVG dimensions from he SVG data to add into the Draw.io XML parameters
4. Obtain the last modified date of the PlantUML file to set as the revision date in the Draw.io XML parameters
5. Create the Draw.io XML file and output to standard out